# INAppStoreWindow Toolbar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I was wondering how I could add a toolbar in the titlebar using [INAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow). I succesfully added InAppStoreWindow in my application but I was thinking how to add a toolbar like the 'AppStore.app' in the center of my titlebar using INAppStoreWindow.

Nowhere on the internet nor stackoverflow has a similer topic about this toolbar inside this INAppStoreWindow method. I hope somebody could tell me if this is possible and how as I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an NSView with the contents of what you want to be on your window's titlebar, and have IBOutlets to both your window and that view, it can be done in 2 lines of code.

*(In this case, the view is `titleView` and the window is `theWindow`)*

```
//Make the titlebar view the same size
[self.titleView setFrameSize:self.theWindow.titleBarView.frame.size];

//Add the view to the window's "titleBarView"
[self.theWindow.titleBarView addSubview:self.titleView];
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, however. I inserted a custom view in MainWindow.xib (I renamed MainMenu.xib) and I can't point it anywhere. How do I need to IBOutlet that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's a website with a tutorial on some things in Cocoa, among which is how to create and deal with IBOutlets - http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_cocoa_two/ - it might be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your tutorial @SebJachec. When I try and link the custom view to the main window view I get nothing but nextKeyView as Outlet. I get the same menu when I try it from the window to the custom view. I need to say that I did not declare or inserted any IBOutlets in my AppDelegate as I don't know how. Here are two screenshots: http://upurs.us/image/43387.png and http://upurs.us/image/43388.png